# Defining action with PyQGIS directly

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using QGIS 3.4.3 and I have created some actions for vector layers. I did it interactively and this part is working.

[image]

Now I wanted to know if there is a mechanism how I could create my actions directly in Python. I don't want to create these actions interactively in QGIS no more.

---

I figured out I can handle it with QgsAction. It works for me.

```
    def my_test(self):
    aLayer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    file1 = self.plugin_dir + "/action1.txt"  
    fw = open(file1, 'r')
    txt = fw.read()
    fw.close()

    action = QgsAction (QgsAction.GenericPython, 'test', txt)
    my_scopes = {'Field'}

    actionManager = aLayer.actions()
    i=0
    for a in actionManager.actions():
     if a.name() == action.name():
      i=1
      break;
    if i == 0:        
     action.setActionScopes(my_scopes)
     actionManager.addAction(action)
```

Now I need to know how I can set flag: "Enable only when editable". The option is disabled per default. I tried to use QgsAction with parameter enabledOnlyWhenEditable=True but it doesn't work.  TypeError: 'enabledOnlyWhenEditable' is an unknown keyword argument

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code to add an action.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
acManager = layer.actions()

acActor = QgsAction(1 , "Fuu", "print 'Baa'", False) 
acManager.addAction(acActor )
```

The QgsAction takes the Argument:

- 1: This is the Action type as described in the [QGIS reference to QgsAction](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsAction.html#afb360f2e24100c27aa1cb40512288f05)
- "Fuu": How your action will be called. It can be any String
- "print 'Baa'": The Function body with """ you can use multiline statements
- False: capture. If this is set to true, the output will be captured when an action is run

Tested with QGIS 2.18. **DISCLAIMER: Posted before the update of the question**

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works also for QGIS 3.4.3. Do you know how I can set flag enabledOnlyWhenEditable to True? It looks for me like enabledOnlyWhenEditable can not be set in constructor.

Comment: You can use the isEditable method of the vector layer e.g: iface.activeLayer().isEditable()