# Set the default action to run when cliquing a feature with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

With help from [Define a action with Python directly (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308523), I managed to write a piece of Python code that associates an action called 'Open File' to a given layer:

```
# add action to open linked document
action = QgsAction(QgsAction.OpenUrl, 'Open file', '[% "full_path" %]')
my_scopes = {'Field', 'Canvas', 'Form', 'Field', 'Layer', 'Feature'}
action.setActionScopes(my_scopes)
actionManager = new_sublayer.actions()
actionManager.addAction(action)
```

Now I would like to set this action as the default action without having to manually select it (like in this screenshot). I can't find how to do this with PyQGIS.

[image]

Maybe using [QgsActionManager.setDefaultAction](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsActionManager.html#qgis.core.QgsActionManager.setDefaultAction)? But if it's truely the good way, I don't now how to generate the second parameter (actionId: QUuid)

Answer (score 1):

Your action ID is already generated, you can retrieve it with `action.id()`.

```
# add action to open linked document
action = QgsAction(QgsAction.OpenUrl, 'Open file', '[% "full_path" %]')
my_scopes = {'Field', 'Canvas', 'Form', 'Field', 'Layer', 'Feature'}
action.setActionScopes(my_scopes)

actionManager = new_sublayer.actions()
actionManager.addAction(action)

# The only line added from your answer
actionManager.setDefaultAction('Canvas', action.id())
```

Unfortunately for me, I think there is a missing signal in the QGIS graphical interface. I need to open and close its vector layer properties to trigger the refresh of the UI to enable the button.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It does work. But I do not have the same problem as yours. 

QGIS version 3.28.1-Firenze
QGIS code revision fde3b8fbb8
Qt version 5.15.2
Python version 3.9.2
On debian 11

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You should use the button "Accept this answer" to really reward me ;-)